# Tomcat 8 Session replication - problems

Tags: tomcat8

need help in figuring out what`s missing with the configuration that have setup - clustering seems to be work fine,

3 node tomcat cluster on 3 machines

machine A - apache webserver A + Tomcat A

machine B - apache webserver B + Tomcat B

machine C - apache webserver C + Tomcat C

all the tomcat instances are aware of other tomcat nodes and during restart, i see tomcat instances are getting added into cluster and each cluster is being aware of presence of other instances.

but up on accessing a web application (where have enabled ) , session is not being replicated across tomcat instances.

Here is my server.xml configuration

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
     channelSendOptions="8">

    <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">

        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                    address="228.0.0.8"
                    bind="machineA ip"
                    port="45564"
                    frequency="500"
                    dropTime="3000" />

        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address="machineA ip"
                  port="4200"
                  autoBind="100"
                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                  maxThreads="6" />

        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
            <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/> 
        </Sender>

        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>

        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
    </Channel>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
            filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;.*\.jpg;.*\.htm;.*\.html;.*\.txt;" />

    <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
               tempDir="D:/cluster/temp/war-temp/"
               deployDir="D:/cluster/temp/war-deploy/"
               watchDir="D:/cluster/temp/war-listen/"
               watchEnabled="false" />

    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>

    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
```

and after going through some online blogs and posts i have moved the  contents to global context.xml file
'$catalina_base/conf/context.xml'

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
     expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
     notifyListenersOnReplication="true" />
```

but still the session is not being replicated across the cluster

please provide your inputs/suggestions